# Show submit button on valid data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show the `.nexto` button once I have valid text in the `input`. Each and every field has its own button so the thing is when I get a valid value of input the button associated with the field should show and other input fields buttons should hide. Thank you.

```js
var required = $('input[required]');
required.on('keyup', function(event) {
  if (this.value !== "") {
    $(this).$('.nexto').show();
  } else {
    $(this).$('.nexto').hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="typeform-element" id="fname">
  <p><span class="list">1</span>&#8594;What's your First Name? *</p>
  <div class="input-element">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Type your answer..." required class="ip-element">
    <p class="blinker">|</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ok-btn">
    <a href="#lname" class="nexto">OK &#10004;</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="typeform-element" id="lname">
  <p><span class="list">2</span>&#8594;What's Your Last Name? *</p>
  <div class="input-element">
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Type your answer..." required class="ip-element">
    <p class="blinker">|</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ok-btn">
    <a href="#email" class="nexto">OK &#10004;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you find `.nexto` element is wrong. From `this` object inside the event handler, do find closest `.typeform-element` and then find `.nexto` child.

Also you need to hide all of the `.nexto` at start.

```js
$('.nexto').hide()

var required = $('input[required]');
required.on('keyup', function (event) {
    var nexto = $(this).closest('.typeform-element').find('.nexto')
    if (this.value !== "") {
        nexto.show();
    } else {
        nexto.hide();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="typeform-element" id="fname">
    <p><span class="list">1</span>&#8594;What's your First Name? *</p>
    <div class="input-element">
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Type your answer..." required class="ip-element">
        <p class="blinker">|</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ok-btn">
        <a href="#lname" class="nexto">OK &#10004;</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="typeform-element" id="lname">
    <p><span class="list">2</span>&#8594;What's Your Last Name? *</p>
    <div class="input-element">
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Type your answer..." required class="ip-element">
        <p class="blinker">|</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ok-btn">
        <a href="#email" class="nexto">OK &#10004;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you need to use jQuery's DOM traversal methods to find the `.nexto` related to the `input` which raised the event.

As such you can use a combination of `closest()`, `next()` and `find()`. Also note that you should use CSS to hide those elements by default. In addition, I'd suggest using the `input` event instead of `keyup`, as it also works for paste events triggered by the mouse. Try this:

```js
var $required = $('input[required]');

$required.on('input', function(event) {
  $(this).closest('.input-element').next('.ok-btn').find('.nexto').toggle(this.value !== "");
})
```

```css
.ok-btn .nexto { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="typeform-element" id="fname">
  <p><span class="list">1</span>&#8594;What's your First Name? *</p>
  <div class="input-element">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Type your answer..." required class="ip-element">
    <p class="blinker">|</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ok-btn">
    <a href="#lname" class="nexto">OK &#10004;</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="typeform-element" id="lname">
  <p><span class="list">2</span>&#8594;What's Your Last Name? *</p>
  <div class="input-element">
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Type your answer..." required class="ip-element">
    <p class="blinker">|</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ok-btn">
    <a href="#email" class="nexto">OK &#10004;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```